# Putting a vector as a Pandas data frame element

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to put a vector as an element of dataframe of Pandas?

Let's say I have two np vectors:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
b = np.array([6, 15, 24])
```

Then, I wonder if I can make some 2x3 table like below.

```
[1,2,3] | [4,5,6] | [7,8,9]
   6    |    15   |   24
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to use the `tolist` method on `np.array` to get pandas to put it how you'd like.

```
pd.DataFrame(dict(a=a.tolist(), b=b)).T
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could pass the `a` and `b` as a list of lists, without needing to transpose.

```
In [2188]: pd.DataFrame([a.tolist(), b.tolist()])
Out[2188]:
           0          1          2
0  [1, 2, 3]  [4, 5, 6]  [7, 8, 9]
1          6         15         24
```

and, more generically,

```
In [2202]: pd.DataFrame(x.tolist() for x in [a, b])
Out[2202]:
           0          1          2
0  [1, 2, 3]  [4, 5, 6]  [7, 8, 9]
1          6         15         24
```